# C theory query in regards to pointers and preventing the misusing of them

Tags: c

I have another exam question that I am revising from and it goes as follows:

"Describe two situations in which misusing pointers in C programs may
lead to problems in the running program, outline the steps you would take to avoid the
problem [18]"

This is an 18 mark question so its a small essay style question would anybody be able to bullet point ideas that I can look into/develop an answer around. So far I have this:

- **Double free problem:** the misuse of pointers can lead to the double free problem to prevent this pay a greater detail of attention to functions that call the free operation
- **memory leaking:** If you aren't careful when passing pointers around you can easily "loose" a pointer, thus you "loose" that memory. to prevent this make sure you know exactly where you are passing pointers to and from, and perform regular tests to see if you are handling the requests properly.

I can't really  think of anymore in all honesty. I can think of problems relating to declaring pointers such as:

```
char* p, s, t; //will only declare one pointer

char *p, *s, *t; //will declare 3 pointers
```

Apart from the above, is there any more I should be aware of? Just an FYI the exam is based on a class that has done C for about 3 months so sorry if I'm missing the obvious!

Comment: i see, i took that example off my teachers slides, i guess he made an error! thanks for pointing that out edit: i tried this and it does in fact work as i stated.

Comment: @tonga No, in that code, `s` and `t` are both of type `int`, not pointers.

Comment: The one that irritates all non C developers. Passing a pointer to one type to a function that's expecting it to point to an other type.

Comment: A frequent misuse of pointers is to assume they are addresses (they are mostly implemented in that way) and rely on that assumption, e.g. by some crude pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Mat: You're right. I took it back.

Comment: If you are looking for problems, try this : `char* p;char b;b=*a;`. Dereferencing a pointer may lead to a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, here are a few problems that weren't mentioned in the question:

- **Accessing null pointers** is obviously silly. Don't do that. Always check the return value of functions that might return null pointers (e.g. `malloc`, `realloc`, `fopen`).
- **Casting pointers** can be disastrous. For example, bus errors can be caused by misaligned access. Avoid casting pointers, unless you've read the C standard and you're certain that you know what you're doing.
- **Returning pointers** into variables or arrays declared within the function is always a bad idea, because as the function returns the variable and/or array is destroyed; the pointer returned points to garbage.
- **Dangling pointers** are particularly notorious in code that uses `malloc`, `free` and `realloc`. A dangling pointer occurs when an object is `free()`d (or `realloc()`'d) and references to it still remain somewhere (e.g. in graphs or linked lists).
- **Passing pointers** of an incorrect type to `scanf`, `printf` and friends is a common cause of problems; read the manuals ([scanf and friends](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html), [printf and friends](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) to make sure you're using the right types.